# JavaScript computer AI

Tags: javascript, jquery, artificial-intelligence

I have a tic-tac-toe game built with JavaScript. I've written the logic for the computer AI part in a function. I'm wanting to call the function on the upper part of my code but it's not working. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to implement the Ai function of the code? I'm wanting to make it so it's hard to win. Any help on what could be wrong ?

Thank You.

This is my JSFiddle link: **http://jsfiddle.net/fnez/rvacaer4/**

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    </header>
    <ul id="board">
        <li id="spot1"></li>
        <li id="spot2"></li>
        <li id="spot3"></li>
        <li id="spot4"></li>
        <li id="spot5"></li>
        <li id="spot6"></li>
        <li id="spot7"></li>
        <li id="spot8"></li>
        <li id="spot9"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <footer id="reset">Reset</footer>
</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = "x";
    var o = "o";
    var turns = 0;

// spots stored in variables 
    var spot1 = $("#spot1");
    var spot2 = $("#spot2");
    var spot3 = $("#spot3");
    var spot4 = $("#spot4");
    var spot5 = $("#spot5");
    var spot6 = $("#spot6");
    var spot7 = $("#spot7");
    var spot8 = $("#spot8");
    var spot9 = $("#spot9");

// function for resetting the board
    function remove() {
            $("#board li").text("");
            $("#board li").removeClass("disable");
            $("#board li").removeClass("o");
            $("#board li").removeClass("x");
            turns = 0;
    }

// Board click 
    $("#board li").on("click", function() {
        console.log(turns);

        if(turns % 2 === 0) {
            $(this).text(x);
            $(this).addClass('disable x');
        } 
        xWins();

        if(turns % 2 !== 0) {
            compCheck();
        } 
        oWins();
        turns ++;
        draw();
    });


    //Checking for Wins

    function xWins() {
        if(spot1.hasClass(x) && spot2.hasClass(x) && spot3.hasClass(x) || 
            spot1.hasClass(x) && spot4.hasClass(x) && spot7.hasClass(x) ||
            spot1.hasClass(x) && spot5.hasClass(x) && spot9.hasClass(x) ||
            spot2.hasClass(x) && spot5.hasClass(x) && spot8.hasClass(x) ||
            spot3.hasClass(x) && spot5.hasClass(x) && spot7.hasClass(x) ||
            spot3.hasClass(x) && spot6.hasClass(x) && spot9.hasClass(x) ||
            spot4.hasClass(x) && spot5.hasClass(x) && spot6.hasClass(x) ||
            spot7.hasClass(x) && spot8.hasClass(x) && spot9.hasClass(x)
            )   {
                alert("Winner is X");
                remove();           
                }
    }

        function oWins() {
        if(spot1.hasClass(o) && spot2.hasClass(o) && spot3.hasClass(o) || 
            spot1.hasClass(o) && spot4.hasClass(o) && spot7.hasClass(o) ||
            spot1.hasClass(o) && spot5.hasClass(o) && spot9.hasClass(o) ||
            spot2.hasClass(o) && spot5.hasClass(o) && spot8.hasClass(o) ||
            spot3.hasClass(o) && spot5.hasClass(o) && spot7.hasClass(o) ||
            spot3.hasClass(o) && spot6.hasClass(o) && spot9.hasClass(o) ||
            spot4.hasClass(o) && spot5.hasClass(o) && spot6.hasClass(o) ||
            spot7.hasClass(o) && spot8.hasClass(o) && spot9.hasClass(o)
            )   {
                alert("Winner is O");
                remove();           
                }
    }

    //Checks for tie 
    function draw() {
        while(turns == 9) {
            alert("It's a tie !");
            remove();
        }
    };

    //Reset button function
        $("#reset").on("click", function() {
            remove();
        });


// Computer AI MOVES 

function compCheck() {
    if (spot1.text == "" && ((spot3.text == "x" && spot2 == "x") || (spot9 == "x" && spot5 == "x") || (spot7 == "x" && spot4 == "x"))) {
        spot1.text(o);
        spot1.addClass('disable o');
        turns++;
    } else {
      if (spot1.text == "" && ((spot1.text == "x" && spot3.text == "x") || (spot8.text == "x" && spot5 == "x"))) {
        spot2.text(o);
        spot2.addClass('disable o');
        turns++; 
        }
        else{
        if (spot3.text == "" && ((spot1.text == "x" && spot2.text == "x") || (spot7.text == "x" && spot5.text == "x") || (spot9.text == "x" && spot6.text == "x"))) {
            spot3.text(o);
            spot3.addClass('disable o');
            turns++;
        }
            else{
            if (spot9.text == "" && ((spot7.text == "x" && spot8.text == "x") || (spot1.text == "x" && spot5.text == "x") || (spot3.text == "x" && spot6.text == "x"))) {
                spot9.text(o);
                spot9.addClass('disable o');
                turns++;
        }
                else{
                if (spot7.text == "" && ((spot9.text == "x" && spot8.text == "x") || (spot3.text == "x" && spot2.text == "x") || (spot1.text == "x" && spot4.text == "x"))) {
                    spot7.text(o);
                    spot7.addClass('disable o');
                    turns++;
        }
                    else{
                    if (spot8.text == "" && ((spot9.text == "x" && spot7 == "x") || (spot2.text == "x" && spot5.text == "x"))) {
                        spot8.text(o);
                        spot8.addClass('disable o');
                        turns++;
        }
                        else{
                        if (spot4.text == "" && ((spot6.text == "x" && spot5.text == "x") || (spot1.text == "x" && spot7.text == "x"))) {
                            spot4.text(o);
                            spot4.addClass('disable o');
                            turns++;
        }
                            else{
                            if (spot6.text == "" && ((spot3.text == "x" && spot9.text == "x") || (spot5.text == "x" && spot4.text == "x"))) {
                                spot4.text(o);
                                spot4.addClass('disable o');
                                turns++;
        }
                                else{
                                if (spot5.text == "" && ((spot3.text == "x" && spot7.text == "x") || (spot9.text == "x" && spot1.text == "x") || (spot6.text == "x" && spot4.text == "x") || (spot8.text == "x" && spot2.text == "x"))) {
                                    spot4.text(o);
                                    spot4.addClass('disable o');
                                    turns++;
        }
                                   else{ // if no spot to block then play these spots....
                                    if (spot5.text == "") {
                                        spot5.text(o);
                                        spot5.addClass('disable o');
                                        turns++;

                                    }
                                        else{
                                        if (spot1.text == "") {
                                            spot1.text(o);
                                            spot1.addClass('disable o');
                                            turns++;

                                    }
                                            else{
                                            if (spot9.text == "") {
                                                spot9.text(o);
                                                spot9.addClass('disable o');
                                                turns++;

                                    } 
                                                else {
                                                if (spot8.text == "") {
                                                    spot8.text(o);
                                                    spot8.addClass('disable o');
                                                    turns++;

                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                    if (spot4.text == "") {
                                                        spot4.text(o);
                                                        spot4.addClass('disable o');
                                                        turns++;

                                    }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }


                                        }
                                   }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    }; 
    });
```

Comment: Tic-tac-toe is ridiculously simple and thus easy to brute-force. There are lots of articles regarding general AI weights, and implementing it into tic-tac-toe should be pretty easy. Once the best you can do against the machine is a draw, your AI is good.

Comment: @Shomz Thank you. I have already created the AI part. It's inside a function. However, that function is not running.

Comment: @mellamokb, which is what I tried to explain. Not sure why you're calling me out for down-voting because this is a legit question... needs a better explanation, but it's fine.

Comment: A simple `turn++` after `xWins()` will cause the computer to move immediately after the player every time - or just skip the check altogether because it will always be player move + computer move on click.  The `O` moves are not showing because you need to check `spot#.text()`, not `spot#.text`.  `Text` is a function.

Comment: @FNunez, you're welcome. Oh I see, the problem is that your code is waiting for a click both for the human player and the computer player, while instead it should wait for the click just for the human player, then check for human win and if not play the computer move and check for the computer win.

Comment: This sort of works... but it has a few bugs: http://jsfiddle.net/rvacaer4/3/.  In some cases the computer doesn't move at all.  Also sometimes the computer tries to go over top of my existing move.  But it's getting there :)  I applied the two changes I mentioned above, and also added a check that player can't move where class `.disabled` is applied (since spot is already taken).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fixed version:

http://jsfiddle.net/rvacaer4/4/

I modified the turns as per my comment and also fixed `*.text` calls.

The AI still has a few bugs (sometimes not playing, not defending properly (playing 1,3,2 always wins), not doing the winning move, etc.), but I'm sure you'll figure it out.

---

If you really want to make it hard for players, I suggest you drop the manual AI and write a recursive check that will figure out the best move in every situation. As I said in the first comment, the game is simple so even the slowest machine today will calculate it in nanoseconds if written properly. That way, humans won't be able to do more than a draw.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I see I had a lot syntax errors on my Ai function. I'll experiment with looping for that recursive check. I know there are articles out there on the topic. I'm still learning so it's still tricky for me to translate the algorithms into JavaScript code.

Comment: Yeah, think of a way to estimate how good is a certain "position" - for example, if I can win in this move, it's 100% good; if AI can win after my move, it's 100%; if I can possibly win in two moves, it's, say, 25% good, etc... And from there AI just needs to sum the values for each possible move and play the best (highest valued) one.